# pivot4j plugin not working properly with pentaho 6.0

Tags: pentaho, pivot4j

I used the marketplace to install pivot4j plugin in pentaho biserver-ce-6.1.0.1-196.
It installed the pivot4j-pentaho-1.0-SNAPSHOT version of the plugin. It is not a stable version. I am using ubuntu 12.04 OS.

Now the problem is that when I try to create a new pivot4j view, it just opens a blank view and no option is displayed. It does not ask for the catalog and the cube name as it ideally should.

I tried to use the stable version pivot4j-pentaho-0.9-plugin but with this, the option to create a new pivot4j view is itself not available. Here is the a screenshot of the pivot4j view diplayed by using the SNAPSHOT version:

[image: Blank view created with new pivot4j option]

Is there a method to load this view with a cube or is it an installation problem?
I am not sure as to what information will be relevant regarding this problem as I am new to pentaho and pivot4j .So let me know, I will update my question with the appropriate info.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error. I checked the error log biserver-ce/tomcat/logs/pentaho.log and I found there is problem in my Schema. After I corrected the schema, it works.

Comment: Please tell us your version of BI server and Pivot4J. Also, share what your log showed and which corrections you made. Thanks.